# How to find similar video with better quality in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, search, video

Sometimes I watch a video on YouTube that has poor quality. I want to find a similar video which has better quality.

Is it possible in YouTube?

Answer (score 3):

Similar videos are posted on the right side of the page in YouTube. However, the similarities are based on Channel, Keywords, and Titles.

Finding a similar video programmatically (via YouTube's API) will get you the same results as the sidebar videos displayed.

Unfortunately, this doesn't guarantee that you will find a higher quality video (try searching for SpongeBob videos some time, SOOO many recorded with a phone pointed at a TV).

Sometimes you can find similar videos posted on other sites doing searches on [Google's Video Search](http://www.google.com/videohp).